# Downloading ImageNet validation set

Tags: imagenet

I have a problem when Downloading the ImageNet validation dataset on colab using wget command.
Using the official site inforced me to create an account which doesn't help me.
Is there a solution to download it or someone could share it with me ?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to download it from using wget?